# V-for with v-if, only duplicate the elements in the parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to display form elements generated from my database.

```
{
 "name":  "Text",
 "order": 1,
 "type":  "text"
},
{
 "name":  "Wysiwyg",
 "order": 2,
 "type":  "wysiwyg"
},
{
 "name":  "Table",
 "order": 3,
 "type":  "table"
}
```

Here's how I do to generate the elements and to respect the order

```
<template v-for="question in questions">
  <div v-if="question.type == 'text'">
    <el-input></el-input>
  </div>

  <div v-if="question.type == 'wysiwyg'">
    <el-input></el-input>
  </div>
</template>
```

It works. And the order is correct.

Only, I have elements that are more complicated. To summarize, I have elements around which I would like that they do not duplicate with the v-for. But let the inner elements duplicate each other.

Example :

```
<el-form-item class="u-m-b-0" v-if="question.type == 'table'">
    <div class="table-3-col__container">
        <div class="table-3-col__title">Année</div>
        <div class="table-3-col__title">Employeur</div>
        <div class="table-3-col__title">Titre de la fonction</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-3-col__inputs">
        <el-input></el-input>
    </div>
</el-form-item>
```

With my technique, everything is duplicated. That's not what I want.

The ideal would be something like this:

```
<el-form-item class="u-m-b-0" v-if="question.type == 'table'">
    <div class="table-3-col__container">
        <div class="table-3-col__title">Année</div>
        <div class="table-3-col__title">Employeur</div>
        <div class="table-3-col__title">Titre de la fonction</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-3-col__inputs">
        <el-input v-for="question in questions.questions"
            v-if="question.type == 'table'"
            :key="question.id" v-model="answers[question.id]"
            class="table-3-col__input">
        </el-input>
    </div>
</el-form-item>
```

Only it does not work. And if I remove the `template` loop and I do like that for all my elements, the order will no longer be met ...

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to 'table' elements that are next to each other in the list to be grouped into the same table. The easiest way is to use a computed property to create a modified version of your database (without affecting the underlying data). This modified version will have any table questions that are next to each other grouped into a single object. In your vue definition you might have:

```
computed: {
//...
  groupedQuestions(){
    return this.questions.reduce(function(grouped, current){
      if(current.type !== 'table'){
        return grouped.concat(current);
      }
      else {
        let last = grouped.pop();

        if(last.type !== 'table'){
          Object.assign({}, current, {questions: [current]});
          // Add a 'questions' field to the table object that will eventually
          // contain all of the questions that are next to each other in the list. 
          // Right now it only has the current question in it.
          return grouped.concat(last).concat(current);
        }
        else {
          // If the previous element in the list was a table, and the current question is a table
          // then add the current question to the previous question's list of questions.
          last.questions.push(current);
          return grouped.concat(last);
        } 
      }
    }, []);
  }
}
```

And then you can do something very similar to what you had in mind.

```
<template v-for="question in groupedQuestions">
  <div v-if="question.type == 'text'">
    <el-input></el-input>
  </div>

  <div v-if="question.type == 'wysiwyg'">
    <el-input></el-input>
  </div>

  <el-form-item class="u-m-b-0" v-if="question.type == 'table'">
    <div class="table-3-col__container">
        <div class="table-3-col__title">Année</div>
        <div class="table-3-col__title">Employeur</div>
        <div class="table-3-col__title">Titre de la fonction</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-3-col__inputs">
        <el-input v-for="question in question.questions"
            :key="question.id" v-model="answers[question.id]"
            class="table-3-col__input">
        </el-input>
    </div>
  </el-form-item>
</template>
```

Comment: Hello @David Sampson, thanks for your help! I'm trying your code, I tried to make several adjustments but nothing helps, I have "error during evaluation" in my computed property.

Comment: 1) Is your data stored in `this.questions` for that component? If not you'll need to adjust where the computed property pulls its data from. 2) Does `groupedQuestions` work and return a data structure that looks like it should?

Comment: Yes, my data are stored in this.questions. I tried to test with `return console.log(current)` in the `.reduce` but it return `undefined`. I target the correct data table. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: At the top of the `groupedQuestions` function, try console.logging `this.questions` and make sure the data is actually good.

Comment: Yes, I receive : `0: {…}
1: {…}
2: {…}
3: {…}…`

Comment: Is `questions` an object with keys 0,1,2,... or an array? If it's an object with ordered keys, instead of `return this.questions.reduce...`, `return Object.values(this.questions).reduce...`.